# Fbchat Login failed. Check email/password

Tags: python-3.x, facebook

```
from fbchat import Client
from fbchat.models import *
import json
import fbchat
from fbchat import Client


def main():
    myUsername = "123456789"
    myPassword = "987654321"
    client = Client(myUsername, myPassword)
    client.send(Message(text="text"), thread_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx, thread_type=ThreadType.USER)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

2 days ago I still logged in and created an automatic chat bot, but now, I can't login.

Error: fbchat._exception.FBchatUserError: Login failed. Check email/password. (Failed on url: https://m.facebook.com/checkpoint/?_rdr)

Can anyone help me fix this error or guide me to login = cookies, I have tried all the ways available on google but still not working.
example: https://github.com/fbchat-dev/fbchat/issues/477

Comment: Are you certain that email and password are correct?

Comment: @JakobF i'm sure exactly, above code has been changed: username, password, thread_id